# switch js src in page with a button

Tags: javascript, html

Can I do this with just javascript in my web page ?

```
<head>
    <script src="trans_func.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="language/English.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="language/Chinese.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

Since it's either English or Chinese , Can I comment out one line of code when I click a button and when I click again it will comment the other line?

Comment: you have to reload the page on button click and moreover along with reload you should load only one js at a time, and on click of button load another js

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki So you are saying this has to been done in the back end instead of the front end?

Comment: yes @jrChen. It would be better if managed in backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of button, you can load the js based on the condition.

```
if(condition!="English") // lang can also be variable which is set from the backend
    {
        document.write('<script src="language/Chinese.js"></script>');
    }
else
    {
        document.write('<script src="language/English.js"></script>');
    }
```

If its based on lanauge:

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
if(userLang!='en-us') // lang can also be variable which is set from the backend
        {
            document.write('<script src="language/Chinese.js"></script>');
        }
    else
        {
            document.write('<script src="language/English.js"></script>');
        }
```

Comment: Can I detect the browser lang to decide which to use?And how Can I do that?